# How to create a .d.ts file that exports an existing module?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, dust.js

I am using both `dust.js` (specifically, dustjs-linkedin) and `dustjs-helpers` in my TypeScript project. I got the typings for dustjs-linkedin off of definitelyTyped, but I am having trouble with the dustjs-helpers. Pretty much, I just want to declare a module called `dustjs-helpers` and have it correctly export the `dustjst-linkedin` module. That means that any time you call `import helpers = require('dustjs-helpers');` you should be able to access all of the functions that regular dust uses by default.

Dust's typings file declares its module as following: `declare module "dustjs-linkedin" { ... }`. I was hoping that I could do something like the following, but I get errors...

```
/// <reference path="../dustjs-linkedin/dustjs-linkedin.d.ts" />

declare module "dustjs-helpers" {
    import dust = require("dustjs-linkedin")
    export = dust;
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Sorry, deleted my answer as it doesn't quite match what you wanted. I don't think TypeScript has typing mechanisms that work with existing modules. For that matter, it could be that what you want is just a `.ts` file, not a definitions file; because you want this actual module to be available under that name (not just to appear to be under that name).

Comment: This works fine for me to compile. How are you compiling this and what errors are you getting? Are they runtime errors because there is no runtime js file in addition to `dustjs-helpers.d.ts`? If so, you're probably looking for what @Katana314 mentioned and you should create a file called `dustjs-helpers.ts` then import and export "dustjs-linkedin" in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit involved but I have verified that this works:

```
declare module "dustjs-helpers" {
    import dust = require("dustjs-linkedin")    

    // Bring into a type
    type Dust = typeof dust;

    // Specify extensions
    type Extensions = {
        anotherFunc : Function;
    }

    // Combine types
    type DustExtended = Dust & Extensions;

    // Create var for export
    var dustExtended: DustExtended;

    // Export
    export = dustExtended;
}
```